# mp3 file and Hyperlink.Follow in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I run this code in a form.
The mp3 file is run but i see also informations from Microsoft Office. why?
Unable to open c:\User\USER\Desktop..... The hyperlink cannot be followed to the destination.

How can i remove these informations or warnings?
Thank you

Private Sub command2_Click()

```
Me.Text14 = DLookup("name", "Table1", "name LIKE '*" & Me.Text12 & "*'")
If Not IsNull(Me.Text14) Then
Set ctl = Me!Command2
With ctl
    .HyperlinkAddress = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\abandon2.wav"
    .Hyperlink.Follow
End With
```

End If

End Sub

Comment: Remember that user directories are locked down to JUST that user. if anyone else other than `USER` uses this form, they won't have permissions to access taht directory.

Comment: My problem is that I can run a sound file on my form without problem. I saw this method has no previous problems but also are exported messages in Microsoft Office. Now I do not know what I do that I can run my sound files without problems.